# What reference lines can be trusted and what points are being dimensioned

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

[image]

Based on the dimensions for the fold lines of the part above, the part is not square in the corners.  It is my understanding that the short sides are actually at an angle other than 90 to the long sides.

1. What lines can I trust as being perpendicular or parallel to the the datum line?
2. What point on the fold lines are the dimensions referencing?  Would it be where the fold line meets the part edge, where the fold lines intersect or some other point as I am misreading this drawing?

Comment: 1) The dimension leaders are vertical, and appear to end where they intersect the 3".35 height leader.
2) Looks like where the flat surface meets the radius - presumably internal dimensions are critical to design intent

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks for your insight.  You basically confirmed what I had assumed.  The first drawing I had that looked like this one was dimensioned slightly different.  Instead of positioning the 4 fold line intersects, it gave two angles for the top left/right corners. Since one corner was 90+x and the other was 90-x.  I falsely assumed that the left, bottom and right sides were all square and the top side was at a skew.